# Feature Request - Bounty Hunter Badge

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is there any reason there isn't a badge/set of badges for individuals that find and answer bounty questions?

Answer (score 7):

Because this would be implemented across all of Stack Exchange instead of on just one site, it'd be better asked on the meta site *for* all of Stack Exchange, [and it has been](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/bounty-hunter-badges).

In summary: Badges are for encouraging/rewarding good behaviour. Bounties already do that by granting unusually large rep rewards (which ignore the daily rep cap, no less!). The question was responded to by creating new badges for *offering* bounties instead.

If you think there's a good argument for revisiting "Boba Fett" badges, I suggest you write a new question on meta.se--but [familiarise yourself with the existing discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=bounty%20and%20badge%20is%3aquestion) and write something which builds on and adds to that conversation, or it'll just get closed as a duplicate of the existing posts.